# Turn Bullets into Shift-Enter linebreaks in Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word

When I write things in word, I often want to paste something, and have it be under a bullet point and have line breaks.  I can do this manually with Shift-Enter, is there anyway I can select a bunch of bulleted items and do this in an automated way?

IE:

Turn:

- foo
- bar
- baz

Into:

- foo
  bar
  baz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the text and Find-Replace (Ctrl+H) ^p with ^l. Might have to re-bullet the 1st one afterwards though.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Bonus's solution. To prevent re-bulleting the first one just start your selection from the end of the first line - in your example that would mean immediately after the second 'o' in 'foo'.

Comment: This really should have been a comment. But I know - I've been there. :)

Comment: Vinayak didn't have enough reputation on Sep. 3 to post a comment.